# How does react typescript usememo deps handle union types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

An online demo can be viewed at https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sammet-jhq4b?file=/src/test2.tsx

The code is as follows

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  //----------------
  // Now use union types here (to get a more precise type derivation)
  const [state, setState] = useState<
    { a: number; c: 1; d?: number } | { b: number; c: 2; d?: number }
  >({
    a: 3,
    c: 1
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setState((pre) => ({ d: Date.now(), ...pre }));
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
  const n = useMemo(() => {
    //  Only .a and .b are used here, so how do I make the .d update not affect here?
    console.log("test2-update", Date.now());
    return (state.c === 1 ? state.a : 0) + (state.c === 2 ? state.b : 0);
  }, [state]); //[state2.c, state2.a, state2.b] will have type error, [state2] will always trigger update
  return <>{n}</>;
}
```

//`[state2.c, state2.a, state2.b]` will have type error, `[state2]` will always trigger update

If I use `[state.c, state.c === 1 ? state.a : state.b]` then I get a warning(https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sammet-jhq4b?file=/src/test3.tsx):

```
React Hook useMemo has missing dependencies: 'state.a' and 'state.b'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)eslint
React Hook useMemo has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

Comment: You could use a helper and destructure.

Comment: @AJcodez Does it mean something like the following implementation? This implementation doesn't feel beautiful enough
```
  const dynamicValue = state.c === 1 ? state.a : state.b;

  const n = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("test4-update", Date.now());
    return dynamicValue;
  }, [dynamicValue]);
···